# Jenkins doesn't release build agent after successful build

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins is running on a Linux machine with a node with 6 building agents.
I have a pipeline Master and a pipeline Slave. Master calling Slave several times (67).
Master code

```
list.each { element ->
    build job: "Slave", 
       parameters: [
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'PARAM', value: element]
       ]
```

The issue is after 5 Slave builds my node is out of build agent knowing that the 5 previous Slave builds ended successfully. The 6th one is pending with the message "Waiting for next available executor on {Node Name}". When I kill the Master pipeline all nodes agents are back as if build agents aren't released after the Slave build end but after the Master build end.

Comment: Try setting `propagate: true`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work. I still have no node agent after 5 builds.

Comment: When you face the deadlock, could you navigate to the agent configuration page (under Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes) and look for the jobs that are withholding it or if it complains about memory, diskspace, etc.?